# SQL multiple data matching

Tags: sql, ms-access

So what I'm trying to do is full shown and described below. I made notes with each step the code should do. I also included the code that I tried. There is one part of the code that I don't know how to do at all. I tried to figure it out but it hasn't been successful (part I marked "XX"). The first part of the code doesn't work. I tested it all separately and the last part works but not fully. It doesn't give me results that I need.

```
-- Pull Open PO# table with [Vendor] that starts with a number (no blanks or letters). Currently table has a lot of rows I don't need.

SELECT
op* case when op.[Vendor] is null AND op.[Vendor] regexp '^[0-9]+' then 
'FALSE' else 'TRUE', pt.[Terms of Pay], md.[Pay Term]

FROM [Master Data] as md, [Open PO# - 6/30/17] as op, [PayT 1/1/17-6/30/17] as pt

--Take that data, match together using op.[Purchase Document] and pt.[Purchase Doc] and pull pt.[Terms of Pay]. Show the payment terms. Basically do a vlookup. I have no idea how to do that. 
XXXX


--Match that data further by [Vendor]&[CoCd] with Master Data [Vendor]&[Comp] 
--For every match, check if [Created on] date falls between [From_Date_Time] and [To_Date_Time]
--If YES, show master [Pay Term] with the rest of data 
--If NO, don't show the record

WHERE ((op.([Vendor]&[CoCd])=md.([Vendor]&[Comp])) AND ((op.[Created on]) 
Between [md].[From_Date_Time] And [md].[To_Date_Time]));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include more detail about the problem.  Do you get an error?  Do you get a different set of data than expected?  "It's not working" is not a sufficient explanation when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let me know if it's better. I just edited the post. The first part just doesn't show any data. The last part works fine. The part in between I am not sure how to do at all and nothing that i tried worked. It's just not giving me data at all.

Comment: Should there be a dot in front of the wildcard field reference `SELECT op.*`? Also, the alias table prefixes in front of concatenated fields in the WHERE clause don't make sense to me. Maye: `WHERE op.[Vendor] & [CoCd]=op.[Vendor] & [Comp] AND op.[Created on] Between [md].[From_Date_Time] And [md].[To_Date_Time];`